Running ansible role two times on the same hosts
I need to execute an ansible role two times with different values set for a set of variables, is there a way to specify for a role from which file to take the values for the list of variables?
For example:
- name: install-vmtest
  hosts: test_nodes
  roles:
    - { role: test, var_file: variables1.yml }
    - { role: test, var_file: variables2.yml }


The desired behavior could be achieved with this playbook:
- name: install-vmtest
  hosts: test_nodes
  tasks:
    - name: Run test role with first set of vars
      ansible.builtin.import_role:
        name: test
        vars_from: variables1.yml
    - name: Run test role with second set of vars
      ansible.builtin.import_role:
        name: test
        vars_from: variables2.yml

Variable files must be located under the role’s vars/ directory.
Source https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html
